# Java Exception after exporting runnable jar

Tags: java, exception, jar, runnable

When I try to run the jar, after exporting it using eclipse, this is what I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ietstesten : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I don't really know why this happens.
I tried importing everything into a new project but it doesn't seem to solve anything.

When I double click the jar I get "Java Exception Occured"

Comment: update your java version

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError, Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161907/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-m)

Answer (score 3):

> This happens because of your `jar` file compiled in `java 1.8` But you
>   are running in the lower version than 1.8

1. Install Java 8
2. Change compliance level to 1.8 in your IDE

## Java Version History

> J2SE 8 = 52
>
> J2SE 7 = 51
>
> J2SE 6.0 = 50
>
> J2SE 5.0 = 49
>
> JDK 1.4 = 48
>
> JDK 1.3 = 47
>
> JDK 1.2 = 46
>
> JDK 1.1 = 45

Comment: I checked if I had the newest version, though, but thanks! Ill double check!

Answer (score 1):

You get the version error when the Jar is compiled with a newer Java version than what you are using to run it with. Did you compile it with Java 8 and are you now running it with Java 7 perhaps?